# building gcc 4.5.2 on amd x86_64 only building 64 bit libraries

Tags: gcc, build

I tried building gcc-4.5.2 from sources on a Debian 64-bit machine.
I ended up having just a 64-bit version of the compiler but no 32-bit.
When I try to build 32-bit applications, I see the following linker error.
When I tried ‘-m32′ options, I’m getting this message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/gcc452/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.5.2/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I do to build gcc properly.

Comment: I think I found the problem, I used --disable-multilib

Answer (score 2):

You also need a 32bit version of "ld" (the linker). ld is found in the binutils package.